# How can I do an edit box appear in the position of an item clicked with angular

Tags: angularjs

If we have a list like:

```
<li id="element1">one</li>
<li id="element2">two</li>
<li id="element3">three</li>
```

and an edit box:

```
<div id="editbox">
    <input id="newName" type="text" value="">
    <input type="button" value="apply" ng-click="changeName()">
</div>
```

I would like to do that when you press in one element from the list, for example, if  I press in the element1, how can I do that the input(box) appear just on the rigth of the element element1 using angular?

The list is dynamic and I'm not sure if I can use like a target where I can associate the id of the element where I have pressed.

I was trying but I cannot get it.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Whether list is dynamic or static  ??

Comment: The list is dynamic and we should use just one edit box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with ng-show (this one toggles):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dummy">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="thing in stuff">
            <span id="{{thing.id}}" ng-click="showThing = !showThing">{{thing.name}}</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="thing.name" ng-show="showThing">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('dummy', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.stuff = [
        {id: 1, name: 'node1'},
        {id: 2, name: 'node2'},
        {id: 3, name: 'node3'},
        {id: 4, name: 'node4'},
        {id: 5, name: 'node6'},
        {id: 6, name: 'node6'},
        {id: 7, name: 'node7'},
        {id: 8, name: 'node8'},
        {id: 9, name: 'node9'},
        {id: 10, name: 'node10'},
    ];
    $scope.selected = false;
}]);
```

Some different options / examples:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLvxzksL/1/)
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLvxzksL/2/)
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLvxzksL/3/)

I was bored so I made you another:
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nLvxzksL/4/)

To get the objthis thing working you need to use controllerAs syntax, take a look at the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) for more information.

For your fiddle, you can look at the changes I made to get it working:
[Updated Fiddle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

You needed to first make a copy of the object you are editing, so you are not immediately changing the actual object. That way when you cancel, it will go back to where it was before.

```
$scope.openEditBox = function(nodeSelected) {
        objthis.currentNodeSelected = nodeSelected;
        objthis.currentEdit = angular.copy(objthis.currentNodeSelected);
        $scope.showThing = true;               
    };
```

the next thing was to add the objthis.currentEdit as the ng-model in the edit box:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="d.currentEdit.name" ng-show="showThing">
```

Then, when you save it you get:

```
$scope.changeName = function() {
        objthis.currentNodeSelected.name = objthis.currentEdit.name;
        console.log($scope.name);
        console.log(objthis.currentNodeSelected);
    };
```

Comment: Thank you Tj Gienger, but imagine that we have a tree view with nodes ( could be representived like a list ) with different ids per each node. Then if you click on the node should  appear the edit box for rename the name of the node. Inside of the edit box we have an input for writing the new name of the node and a button for applying the action so change the current name for the new one. Do you know how I can do it with angular? I don't know if I can use a target where the value of the target should be the id node where you click. Thank you so much for the example on jsfiddle.

Comment: what about each "node" is unique? Whatever it is, if you can display it, you can add it to any part of the element. Give me an example of what each node looks like and I'll update my fiddle

Comment: Updated code + fiddle. You can bind the anything from the object into the id of the element if you want. When it comes to the variable used in ng-show it doesn't have to be different because each ng-repeat creates a separate scope.

Comment: Exactly each node is unique so should have an id different. I hope that this example is OK for you: <div id="nodelist"> <li id="node1" ng-click="showEditBox()">node1</li><li id="node2" ng-click="showEditBox()">node2</li><li id="node3" ng-click="showEditBox()">node3</li> <li id="node4" ng-click="showEditBox()">node4</li>     you have to know that is a dynamic list and when you click should be appear on the right of the node the edit box. How can I associate on the edit box the  node 1 for example, I mean exist something like a target="node1" that I can put on the edit box ?

Comment: Did you even look at the fiddle?

Comment: same, but with a function and 1 edit box [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLvxzksL/2/)

Comment: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nLvxzksL/3/) and another one where the box takes the place of the item you're working on.

Comment: Wauuu Tj Gienger , thank you so so much!!! I think that the last example with save and cancel button is fine for me. I think so. Thank you mate, you are a crack!! I will see in more details the example and any problem I'm going to tell you. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi Tj Gienger, how can I put the editBox section on the right where I have clicked? This is the example that I made. Jsfiddle.net/nLvxzksL/5/

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect the changes I made to your fiddle

Comment: I see the problem. I have a question, its possible to put the editBox on the right of the node that you have clicked? Because now the editBox is placed at the bottom but I would like to know the way to put that edit box on the right of the node that you click. Something that we can put on the block of editBox like a target or something similar with the id of the node. Thanks for your work.

Comment: use css to place elements where you want on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-show`:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/xzp4mk46/)

HTML:

```
<li id="element1"><a href="#" ng-click="selected = 1">one</a> <input id="box" type="text" value="" ng-show="selected === 1"></li>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('dummy', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.selected = false;
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you Michelem, but imagine that we have a tree view with nodes ( could be representived like a list ) with different ids per each node. Then if you click on the node should  appear the edit box for rename the name of the node. Inside of the edit box we have an input for writing the new name of the node and a button for applying the action so change the current name for the new one. Do you know how I can do it with angular? I don't know if I can use a target where the value of the target should be the id node where you click. Thank you so much.